# Plivo -- Calling ID

Tags: plivo

I have set up my android phone with Plivo SIP settings to be able to answer/make calls from my cell phone.

It works great !

--

However, when calling someone from my Plivo SIP account, the number displayed (to the receiver) is something like: `1000000000@212.100.254.149`

**Is there a way to configure my caller I ?** to something more friendly :)

Thank you

Comment: Is there a programming question hiding in here ?

Comment: Well I guess it has to be with https://www.plivo.com/docs/xml/dial/ but not sure... Feel free to close my question if not specific enough, will understand ;)

Comment: @abernier I am getting same info any workaround you found please help me for that

Answer (score 0):

In the [Plivo Dashboard](https://manage.plivo.com), configure the Plivo application associated with your endpoint to use the following answer url:

```
http://plivodirectdial.herokuapp.com/response/sip/route/?DialMusic=real&CLID=14155551234
```

And replace 14155551234 with a Plivo number in your account that you want to use for your caller ID

Comment: it works :) however can you refer some plivo documentation about that `CLID` parameter ? thx

Comment: see https://github.com/plivo/directdial/blob/master/python/app.py#L12 and https://github.com/plivo/directdial/blob/master/python/app.py#L53 for details of the implementation and https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/dynamic-caller-id/ for more generic info about setting the caller id.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be so late, but there is a way to do that. You can add headers in the outgoing call and on your response xml read them and process them.